# Как сделать авторизацию (python django)

Tags: python, django

У меня есть 2 модели:
Client (fio,card),
Card (number,pinkode).
Связь между ними один ко многим. (1 клиент, много карт).
Есть форма авторизацию, запрашивает номер карты и пинкод.
Моя задача проверить номер карты и пин на существующие в бд и если найдется совпадения вывести информацию о клиенте. (Его фио). Проблема в том, что я только на стадии изучения django и не совсем понятно как это можно сделать. Я пробовал различные варианты. Сейчас остановился на варианте, это во views.py, проверять валидная ли форма. После чего получать информацию из бд, проерять на совпадения и если найти выводить инфу. Но как это реализовать тоже непонятно. К примеру, не совсем понятно, как получить данные из бд во views.py. В любом случае, вообщем, крайне буду благодарен за помощь. Помогите любым кодом или описанием или еще чем-то.

forms.py

```
class AuthForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Card
        exclude = 'money',
```

views.py

```
def authorization(request):
    form = AuthForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        ...

    context = {
        'form': AuthForm()
    }
    return render(request, 'TIbank/authorization.html', context=context)
```

Comment: прикрепите код моделей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На основе имеющихся данных:

Наверное для вашей цели, в форме стоит указывать конкретные поля, а не `exclude`

```
class AuthForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Card
        fields = ['number', 'pincode']
```

Это нужно, если у вас добавятся поля вроде `card_holder` или `valid_till` которые бывают на банковских картах. При добавлении любого поля - он появится и в форме, если не органичить через `fields`.

Что касается вывода ФИО если данные карты совпали

```
if form.is_valid():
    card = Card.objects.filter(**form.cleaned_data).first()
    owner = card.owner  # Или как там у вас указано
```